# Analyzing correlated data in R: Linear, Ridge regression, PCR

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I've got a time series of observations of 5 variables `y, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4` and the task is to find which of the `x`es are responsible for the changes in `y`. Now the problem is that all of them are strongly cross-correlated and exhibit collinearity. `x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4` don't have hidden components inside which are common to them pairwise or in any other way - they are just naturally correlated.

Predictably, linear regression gives unreasonable results with coefficients changing wildly after removing one of the variables, which is a normal picture for highly-collinear data.

As advised on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Remedies_for_multicollinearity), some of the remedies for multicollinearity are using ridge regression and principal component regression. However, when I use `lm.ridge` method, it gives me exactly the same coefficients as `lm`.

Can PCR help in such a case and if so, what is an easy way in R to retrieve the coefficients and p-values from it? Something like a summary table for `lm` function.

Comment: for `MASS::lm.ridge` you probably neglected to set a non-zero `lambda` (penalty coefficient), in which case the function defaults to `lambda=0`, i.e. regular unpenalized regression.  (The documentation for `lm.ridge` is quite sketchy -- you probably have to go get a copy of *Modern Applied Statistics with S* (Venables and Ripley) if you want guidance on how to use this function ...

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, will check it out and report here...

Comment: Very nice book indeed - thank you for pointing to it, and there is a seemingly legal free pdf version available online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at

> Dormann et al. (2012). Collinearity: a review of methods to deal with
>   it and a simulation study evaluating their performance. 
>   [paywall](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1600-0587.2012.07348.x/abstract), [alternative link](http://www.biom.uni-freiburg.de/Dateien/PDF/Dormann2012Ecographyearlyonline)

for a review of available methods.

R-Code and data is available [here](http://www.biom.uni-freiburg.de/Dateien/PDF/CollinearityRcodeData) :)

Comment: Thank you! Looks interesting, will get back after checking it out.

Comment: Very nice, some useful info inside and helpful examples. Thanks!

Comment: Hello.
What R package do you advise to use for Ridge Regression? glmnet, bigRR, Mass, other?
Any of them able to deal with repeated measures (random effects)?